# Problem while redirecting to subdirectory page?

Tags: url, web-config, plesk

I have a asp.net app, in which my start up is inside a directory Home of the root. That ~/Home/Home.aspx should be mine startup page. But when I upload it to my production server, and I type the url it displays nothing. So I need some settings in my web.config so that it will automatially get redirected to that page.

My host is using Parallel plesk 9.5.x

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Default URL in Web.Config for website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772084/setting-default-url-in-web-config-for-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find how to change the default document of a web in plesk
http://kb.hyve.com/wiki/DefaultDocumentsHowDoIChangeTheDefaultDocumentOnPlesk

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this:
       response.redirect("page.aspx")
on the index page?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new page on your site root with name 'index.htm' in that page add the following meta tag to redirect the user to home page.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=home/home.aspx">
```

The number in the content attribute is the time, in seconds, until the page should be redirected. Then, separated by a semi-colon (;) you write the URL to the page to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set default page with Windows Plesk:

- Login to Plesk
- Click your domain
- Click Web Directories
- Click Preferences

In the option as Documents, you can set the order of which files are searched. If you want index.php instead of index.html, you would make sure that the index.php is listed above index.html.
You can use the same option to set non existing file as the preferred filename.