# Startup Page on host server doesn't work in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

In visual studio MyProject properties I set the Login.aspx page as startup page and it works fine when I use the local host, however when I publish to the external host server the startup page is ignored and the aspx page in the URL is displayed. What am i doing wrong? host server has IIS6, 3.5 FrameWork

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Startup Action, and specific page in this case is only used for Debugging purposes, not for the initial page to load on your web host.

If your web host is using IIS7, you can use the `<defaultDocument>` [web.config element](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument).

Otherwise, you can set the value in IIS ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772084/setting-default-url-in-web-config-for-website/772095#772095)), or possibly find a workaround elsewhere.

Comment: If you have control over it, you can [set it in IIS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772084/setting-default-url-in-web-config-for-website), or they will need to. Or you'll have to search for a workaround.

Comment: I am new to this but can I set it to redirect to login.aspx when the MainPage.aspx loads? I added to the original question.

Comment: @tszoro You may consider asking that part as a separate question, because you're asking 2 different things. What you have above should work, but there could be something else going on.

Comment: Thank you. Question modified. Your answers help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The startup page is only for the ASP.NET Development server that is created by Visual Studio..used for testing & debugging your code.

Since you're publishing to IIS 6.5, you can set your default documents(s) on the website's Documents tab in IIS. Add your default starting page to the list there & move it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

On II6 if you right click the web site --> Properties then go to Documents, there is a Enable Default Document.  That list is where the default document is set.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will also contact the tech support for host server about this setting.